# Galleon: Adding ActiveMQ with CLI on Wildfly 23+ not working

Tags: wildfly, jboss-cli

Since Wildfly 23 i have the problem that i cant add the activemq configutration with cli anymore.
Executing `/subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=:add` return always an error stating that the default security domain "other" is missing (which was removed in version 23).

With the line `/subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default:write-attribute(name=elytron-domain, value=myDomain)` i could add another security domain but thats not possible if the above command fails.
Is there a way to get this working? Overriding the default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define an elytron security domain to secure your server (or before WildFly 25 a legacy security domain such as 'other').
With WildFly 26 you can just disable security (cf. https://issues.redhat.com/browse/WFLY-15236 )

Answer (score 0):

Combining both commands did the trick:

```
/subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=:add(elytron-domain,myDomain)
```